# Ampersand conflict when using align inside table

Tags: tables, align, nesting, ampersand

I am trying to use an `align` environment inside a `tabular` environment. Whenever I use an `&` character inside the `align` environment, there seems to be a conflict, i.e., the following works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|m{0.3\textwidth}|m{0.7\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Compact form} & \textbf{Expanded form} \\
            \hline
            \begin{equation*}y=\left(x+a\right)^6\end{equation*}
             & \begin{align} y =x^6+6x^5a+15x^4a^2+20x^3a^3+15x^2a^4 \nonumber\\ +6xa^5+a^6 \end{align} \\
             \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table with misaligned equation]

but the following does not work (note the `&` characters inside `align`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|m{0.3\textwidth}|m{0.7\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Compact form} & \textbf{Expanded form} \\
            \hline
            \begin{equation*}y=\left(x+a\right)^6\end{equation*}
             & \begin{align} y & =x^6+6x^5a+15x^4a^2+20x^3a^3+15x^2a^4 \nonumber\\ & +6xa^5+a^6 \end{align} \\
             \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

TeXStudio gives me the following error: `! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \align.`

My goal is to obtain something like this
[image: table with aligned equation]

Is there any way to fix this, e.g. by setting an ampersand replacement for  `align` to avoid the conflict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Group the `align` with braces `{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|m{0.3\textwidth}|m{0.7\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Compact form} & \textbf{Expanded form} \\
            \hline
            \begin{equation*}y=\left(x+a\right)^6\end{equation*}
             & {\begin{align} y & =x^6+6x^5a+15x^4a^2+20x^3a^3+15x^2a^4 \nonumber\\ 
                                & +6xa^5+a^6 \end{align}} \\
             \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really should fix that